# IF EXISTS for multiple data sources/databases

Tags: sql

Is there a standard way to check if a table exists in a database using only pure SQL and nothing that is database specific? Basically an equivalent of IF EXISTS that will work when used on any datasource (SQL compliant of course).

UPDATE

How can I make the examples given work in this statement?

```
IF(SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'clusterTable200m' 
AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE')) 
BEGIN  
SELECT 'Exists' 
END 
ELSE  
BEGIN  CREATE TABLE clusterTable200m(CLUSTER_ID int NOT NULL, CELL_GEOM   geometry NOT NULL, CELL_CENTROID geometry NOT NULL , CLUSTER_CENTROID   geometry , CLUSTER_EXTENT  geometry , NUM_POINTS  int , FEATURE_PK  int , PRIMARY KEY (CLUSTER_ID)) SELECT 'Complete'  
END
```

UPDATE

The above code is a minds eye of how I want the SQL to work but it has been pointed out that I cannot have the IF without a stored procedure or similar and this is out of the question. I also cannot reference for example sysobjects from ms sql server as this is specific to that data source.

I know it is a tricky one but if anyone can offer a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Ok so as it stands the only work around I have thought of is as follows:

```
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

        OleDataBaseConnection oleDataBaseConnection = new OleDataBaseConnection();

        bool tableExists = true;

        try
        {
            oleDataBaseConnection.OleExecutePureSqlQuery(sqlQuery);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            if (exc.Message.ToUpper().Contains("EXIST"))
            {
                tableExists = false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This code will attempt to return all items from the table(will be changed to just attempt a return of the first record to prevent performance impact) and if it fails it checks the error message for the word exists (so as not to supress other exceptions) If the word exists is present I assume that the table is not in the database. Then further down my code if the table does not exist then I run the pure SQL to create the new table. This is the only work around I have though of so far and I welcome any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, for those systems that comply:

```
SELECT EXISTS
       ( SELECT *
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'CatalogName'
           AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName' 
           AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
       ) AS answer
FROM dual              --- this may be required in some systems.
```

**Information_schema docs**:

- [SQL-Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/information-schema.html)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html)
- [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmstcatalog.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are the catalog and schema necessary to this function as I may not know what they are at the time of running the sql. The only thing I will be aware of is the table name.

Comment: You can remove those parts from the where. And add `AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` to distinguish tables from views.

Comment: And also be aware that diffefent users with different privileges will not be seeing the same view.

Comment: I have attempted to add the example into my SQL as shown in the update in the original post. What is wrong here? It is giving me the error that it is not valid SQL. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: In MYSQL, I think that an `IF` statement has to be inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Well I am simply writing the SQL into a string and passing it through to the database using the ExecuteReader() method found in OLE. One of the requirements of the project is to make the SQL and all functionality independent of the database so a stored procedure is out of the question. Its not the best idea I know but I am fairly new here and upper management make the decisions so as usual I just have to make the most of a bad situation. That was the reason for asking whether it was possible in pure sql without using stored procedures etc.

Comment: I tried without the IF and many other variations and it complained again as it was not stored in a procedure. I have modified the OP with an update showing what I have now got working as a work around however there is a datatype that I need to use (or an equivalent of in other databases) called sdo_geometry which is now causing issues. I think it will be a different topic however as it is not really related to my original question. Thanks for the help with this probem though. I think the idea to do it in this way by the management is a very poor one and will throw up a great many issues.

Comment: If you know the database name, you could also consider the approach trying `SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.TableName` and catching the error (if the table doesn't exist).

Comment: And previously, I meant the query without any `IF` or `BEGIN`, just one `SELECT` query. You should also note that Information_Schema is not available in all systems.

Comment: Yes the lack of the Information_Schema was one of the problems I had. At this stage I am not sure whether I will even get the privilege of knowing the database name prior to having to carry out the query. I am pretty sure I will have the connection string to work with which may shed some light but the idea is to not have to care about what data source we have. It is a very frustrating project. I think I need to get together with my project manager and have a discussion about whether this is the correct way forward as I certainly have my reservations as do others at the company.

Comment: I agree it's not trivial. And there is no generic way that works in all systems, especially if you don't knwo before-hand what system you are working against. But you do can write specific (different) ways that work in different systems, like `sysobjects` for SQL-Server, and just have your code try them all, one by one, until one succeeds (or all fail).

Comment: Yes I wouldnt have a problem if I could know the datasource and code slightly different querys for each possible data source. I think it is just a case of upper management having no idea how these things work and having unrealistic expectations with little technical background. Sadly this is the first project I have been given at this company so don't want to cause a fuss. All I can do is try and prove that it is not the best idea by way of raising issues with the project manager as I work through. Lucky me =)

Comment: My point is that you can still write (slightly or greatly) different querys for each possible data source. Then try them all until one works :) It would mean a lot of try-catch blocks but it would work in the end.

Comment: Ah so you mean write a function that works for Oracle for example and then run that on the others. If it doesnt work then just try a different one. A bit (or an awful lot) of trial and error. The problem is that some of the databases are a bit obscure and some are open source which means that they are unlikely to support some of the spatial functions and datatypes that are used in others. If it was possible to store things on the database then this could simply be solved by having a custom type on each database which contained the data in the form I need and then accessing that from mid tier.

Answer (score 0):

//sql server 2000

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='tablename') 
        SELECT 'tablename exists.' 
ELSE 
        SELECT 'tablename does not exist.'
```

[reference](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-determine-if-a-table-exists-in-a-sql-server-database.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to have BEGIN and END statements in this example?

Comment: @CSharpened you only need the BEGIN and END for multiline statements.